# How to prevent OWIN from processing a route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I've got an ASP.NET MVC5 application using Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1 configured for CookieAuthentication. In my application I have a route that I want to use to generate a PDF based off of a Razor view using Essential Objects EO.Pdf library.

When the PDF generation process kicks off, a second request to the server is made but there are no auth cookies present in that request. OWIN denies the request and redirects to the login page.

Is it possible to tell OWIN to ignore a particular route? Here is my Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        }
    }
```

This is the resulting exception, seemingly from Owin:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String key, String[] value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Why is there a second request?  That sounds like the real issue...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the PDF library goes about generating the PDF response but it always results in the same IIS error (updated in the question)

Comment: Checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337263(v=vs.113).aspx. But I agree with @ErikPhilips, I would get to the root of the underlying issue.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll keep digging for what may be causing OWIN to be reached with no authenticated user in context.

Comment: Ok... how is the second request being made.. I'm sure there is some code somewhere that does it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem was entirely related to my browser cookies. On a whim I went incognito and it worked. Extremely frustrating. Then I switched back to my normal window, deleted my cookies, re-authenticated and everything was fine in OWIN land.